# on deploy MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit: Error VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: truffle, multisignature, gnosis

I'm trying out a very simple js script through truffle to create the [Gnosis multisig wallet](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/issues/82) on a local testrpc net. However it always fails.

JS deploy file:

```
const MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit = artifacts.require("./MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.sol")
module.exports = async function (callback) {
  let wallet
  try {
    wallet = await MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.new([multisigWalletAddress1, multisigWalletAddress2], 2, multisigWalletDailyLimit)
    console.log(`MultisigWallet: ${wallet.address}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error → ', error)
  }
}
```

Command:

```
truffle exec exec/KickStarter/deploy.js --network testrpc
```

Error:

```
error →  Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43303:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331156:36
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:315621:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70564:24)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1086:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you check all values you submit to `MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit`.

In this case the error was thrown because the `multisigWalletAddress2` was '0x0'. It requires a second address.